# axml does not load in vs2017

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, visual-studio-2017

I have a xamarin android project.
If I open this project in vs2015 and load a axml into the designer view everything is ok. If I do the same in vs2017 I get a error:
***Something went wrong
Exception of type 'Xamarin.AndroidDesigner.Java.JavaErrorMessageException' was thrown***
The solution it's self builds without any errors.
Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

Check the Android settings in (Tools->Options->Xamarin->Android Settings). It would appear that the JDK and android SDK locations do not automatically get updated between versions of VS (well they didn't on mine).

Comment: I adjusted the location in vs 2017 as they were set in 2015. But there I get the error : 
Warning  Android Designer could not run because: Your Java version (1.7.0) is too old. You must have at least 1.8 installed.
Please install it or set Java Development Kit path for Oracle 1.8+

Comment: yeah your VS 2015 is probably running an old version of the VS plugin, whereas the 2017 is using the latest. Suggest doing as the message said, install 1.8 JDK and make sure it's set in the options as above. Note, if you are using the xamarin forms previewer you will actually need the 64bit version

Comment: When installing vs2017 jdk 1.8 was installed and the location was set in vs2017 accordingly. When I set the location back to jdk1.8 - what I did again - I am back to the issue, this thread started with.